# iOS MapView add MKPointAnnotation which coordinate is (0, 0) not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to add annotations on `MKMapView`. The annotations can show up when the coordinates are not `(0, 0)`, but when I set the annotation's coordinate as (0, 0), the annotation view can NOT show up.

On the iPhone XS simulator and device, only one annotation showing(location (10, 0)), the location(0, 0) not show up.

It seem that the (0, 0) annotation is add at the bottom of the map, not at the west side of Africa.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // Add Annotation
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0);
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    MKPointAnnotation *annotationZero = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotationZero.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10, 0);
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotationZero];
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]]) {
        static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"map_annotation";
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        }
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"annotation_icon"];
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `(0,0)` as coordinate. Use `(0.0000001, 0.0000001)` instead.

Comment: Yes, Finally, I used the `(0.000000001, 0)` as work around. But the coordinate `(0, 0)` is a legal location in the GPS location system. Maybe Apple made some boundary conditions protection in the API source code.

Answer (score 2):

I started with a test using `Swift` and `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0,0)` worked fine, so the problem isn't related to a device but it is language specific *issue*.

You cannot use `(0,0)` in **objective-c**, instead use `DBL_MIN`, which is the smallest number possible, like so:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(DBL_MIN, DBL_MIN)
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, and thanks for you help me correct the question description above. ^_^ Thank you very much.